# Value type error during changing of email addresses and aliases via PowerShell ISE

Tags: powershell, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

I trying to do bulk change of distribution lists, using Powershell script, but didn't made it far.

I importing new addresses and aliases from a .CSV file and seems like this is the issue. Because when I assigning an address and an alias to an exact DL, then it all fine. Or maybe the script written bad.

Error message:

> Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'EmailAddresses'. Cannot convert value "System.Collections.ArrayList" to type "Microsoft.Exchange.Data.ProxyAddressCollection". Error: "The address
> 'SMTP:@{DisplayName=TEAM_A; PrimarySmtpAddress=a_dl@company.com; Alias=a_dl@company.org}.PrimarySmtpAddress' is invalid: The address '@{DisplayName=TEAM_A; PrimarySmtpAddress=a_dl@company.com;
> Alias=a_dl@company.org}.PrimarySmtpAddress' is not a valid SMTP address.
> Parameter name: address
> Actual value was @{DisplayName=TEAM_A; PrimarySmtpAddress=a_dl@company.com; Alias=a_dl@company.org}.PrimarySmtpAddress."
> + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Set-DistributionGroup], ParameterBindin...mationException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Set-DistributionGroup
> + PSComputerName        : outlook.office365.com*

The script:

```
Connect-ExchangeOnline
$psmtpa = Import-Csv C:\_temp\Excange\PrimarySMTPAddress.csv
ForEach ($name in $psmtpa){
    ForEach ($email in $psmtpa){
        ForEach ($alias in $psmtpa){
            Set-DistributionGroup "$name.DisplayName" -EmailAddresses SMTP:$email.PrimarySmtpAddress,$alias.Alias
                }
        }
}
```

And the .CSV look like this:
[image]

PS And yeah, I trying to perform it, using PowerShell ISE, instead of writing a one-liner in PowerShell app. Also, I tried *WindowsEmailAddress*, but powershell don't understand it what is it.

Comment: Remove the `foreach($alias in $psmtpa)` loop completely, and then pass `-EmailAddresses "SMTP:$($email.PrimarySmtpAddress)","smtp:$($email.Alias)"` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things to note, first, the double quotes on `"$name.DisplayName"` are *stringifying* the object `$name` and appending `.DisplayName` to it. **Remove them**.

```
$object = [pscustomobject]@{
    foo = 'var'
}

"$object.foo" # => @{foo=var}.foo
$object.foo   # => 'var'
```

Second thing to note, on:

```
-EmailAddresses SMTP:$email.PrimarySmtpAddress,$alias.Alias
```

If you're looking to add a **Primary** and **Secondary** SMTP address, as [Mathias pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71223444/value-type-error-during-changing-of-email-addresses-and-aliases-via-powershell-i#comment125895421_71223444), you should be using:

```
-EmailAddresses "SMTP:$($email.PrimarySmtpAddress)", "smtp:$($email.Alias)"
```

If instead, `$email.Alias` is actually an **Alias**, then you should be using:

```
-EmailAddresses "SMTP:$($email.PrimarySmtpAddress)" -Alias $email.Alias
```

See [Subexpression operator `$( )`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#subexpression-operator--) for more info.

Lastly, you don't need 3 loops, 1 should be enough to loop over your CSV:

```
$psmtpa = Import-Csv C:\_temp\Excange\PrimarySMTPAddress.csv
foreach ($object in $psmtpa) {
    Set-DistributionGroup $object.DisplayName -EmailAddresses "SMTP:$($object.PrimarySmtpAddress)", "smtp:$($object.Alias)"
}
```