# importing alias addresses into AD from a CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, import, alias

I have been given a csv with 2 columns one headed samaccountname and the other proxyaddresses
I run this script to add the proxyaddresses to the accounts in the csv and it fails, any ideas why please?
scipt

```
Import-Csv "c:\scripts\testproxy.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    try{
        Set-ADUser -Identity $_.samaccountname -add @{Proxyaddresses=$_.Proxyaddresses -split ";"} -ErrorAction Stop
        Write-Host $_.samaccountname complete! -ForegroundColor Green
    }catch{
        Write-Host 'Failed : ' -NoNewline
        Write-Host $_.samaccountname -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}
```

result

```
Import-Csv "c:\scripts\testproxy.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    try{
        Set-ADUser -Identity $_.samaccountname -add @{Proxyaddresses=$_.Proxyaddresses -split ";"} -ErrorAction Stop
        Write-Host $_.samaccountname complete! -ForegroundColor Green
    }catch{
        Write-Host 'Failed : ' -NoNewline
        Write-Host $_.samaccountname -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}
Failed : 
Failed : 
Failed :
```

Anyone know why it failed or have a working script to do this? Many thanks

I was expecting the sam account names in the csv to have the proxy address in the csv applied to their AD account.

Comment: without seeing the actual error is hard to tell why it could fail

Comment: `$_` inside the `catch` block no longer refers to the same thing

Comment: In the catch put `Write-Warning "Failed: $($_.Exception.Message)"` so you at least know why it failed. Perhaps the user with `$_.samaccountname` was not found but there could be more reasons for failure. P.S. Using `-Add` and a Hashtable requires you to use the **proper LDAP casing** for the property, so `proxyAddresses=...` instead of `Proxyaddresses=...`. Also, the new values need to be entered using a **strongly typed string array**. (needs cast to `[string[]]`)

Answer (score 0):

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/840318/update-ad-attributes-from-a-csv-file

And: [Value type error during changing of email addresses and aliases via PowerShell ISE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71223444/value-type-error-during-changing-of-email-addresses-and-aliases-via-powershell-i)

Somethings to check:

- Are you sure the CSV is properly formatted with the correct delimiter (;)?
- Do you have the right permission in AD to update proxyaddresses?
- You need to check if the samaccountname values in the CSV file match the samaccountname values in Active Directory. I've had issues where this is not consistent.
- Finally check the CSV and make sure there are no spaces or unnecessary punctuation, or if there is you are properly handling it in your script.